# OAuth user cap - deleting test users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

Is there a way around the rule where Google says that test users that you remove from your unpublished app will still count against the allowed user cap?

Our app is still in private beta so we're okay with the limit of 100 users but I don't get why if we remove a user, it won't free up space for another tester.